# Error with module bootstrapping

Tags: zend-framework, bootstrapping, zend-view

my application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
test.bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/test/Bootstrap.php"
test.bootstrap.class = "Test_Bootstrap"

appnamespace = "Application"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"

resources.view[] =
test.resources.view[] = 

db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
db.params.dbname = "money"
db.params.username = "root"
db.params.password = "**************"

resources.modules[] =
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

application/modules/test/bootstrap.php

```
class Test_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initLeftMenu()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('View');
        $view = $this->getResource('View');
        $view->render('index/_left_menu.phtml'); // <-- here error
    }
}
```

have a problem with `$view->render`

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'no
>   view script directory set; unable to determine location for view
>   script' in C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php:973 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(884):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->_script('_left_menu.phtm...') #1
>   E:\www\money2\application\modules\test\Bootstrap.php(19):
>   Zend_View_Abstract->render('_left_menu.phtm...') #2
>   C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(667):
>   Test_Bootstrap->_initLeftMenu() #3
>   C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(620):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('leftmenu') #4
>   C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(584):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap(NULL) #5
>   C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Modules.php(124):
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap() #6
>   C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Mod in
>   C:\ZendFramework\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php on line 973

any idea?

Comment: Why don't you start sentences with upper case characters?

Comment: Somebody needs to edit this question later to meet the SO standards. This is a real people community, other folks are reading your posts over and over. You could consider some additional micro time to write the question properly as we are taking the time to figure out the answer for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find own salvation:
application.ini

```
test.resources.view.basePath = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/test/views/"
```

Comment: this working for now but eventually you will get yourself in trouble.

Comment: @Xerkus tell me why? the problem, as i said above in: _no view script directory set_. in any way i mast only set directory. ather things going normal

Comment: application resource View replaces ViewRenderer helper and view instance. As result when you use it in module, it replaces view instance configured in main bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

remove `test.resources.view[] =`

View resource in module replaces view from main bootstrap.

Hint:
`$this->getApplication();` in module bootstrap will return main bootstrap
Use it to bootstrap and retrieve view.

```
class Test_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initLeftMenu()
    {
        //main bootstrap, injected by modules resource
        $bootstrap = $this->getApplication();
        $bootstrap->bootstrap('View');
        $view = $bootstrap->getResource('View');
        $view->render('index/_left_menu.phtml'); // <-- here error
    }
}
```

btw, bootstrap isn't a good place to render something. Consider moving it to more appropriate places. Action helper for example.
Also check [this blog post](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html)

Comment: will try you recommendations today evening

Comment: same problem. _no view script directory set; unable to determine location for view script_

Comment: @Subdigger how you retrieve your view instance?